# Meteor useraccounts:bootstrap with flowrouter

Tags: meteor, user-accounts, flow-router, meteor-useraccounts

Still in my fresh beginning with meteor, I'm having troubles setting up useraccounts:bootstrap with flowrouter.
So far, I was using accounts-ui for prototyping and all worked perfectly.

I've then modify the following packages:

```
remove accounts-ui
add useraccounts:bootstrap
add useraccounts:flow-routing
```

I also (still) have :

```
accounts-password
kadira:flow-router
arillo:flow-router-helpers
```

There seem to be no error in the console, regarding any eventual missing package.
*let me know if you need to know more about the packages I'm using.*

**My problem is :** 
When I try to go to the route `localhost:3000/signin` or `join`, it loads for few seconds and then redirects me to localhost:3000 without displaying any auth related content. 
I presume it might be my routes which are wrong.

here they are :

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  name: 'App.home',
  action(params, queryParams) {
    BlazeLayout.render('App_body', {main: 'signin'});
  },
});

AccountsTemplates.configure({
  showForgotPasswordLink: true,
  defaultTemplate: 'Auth_page',
  defaultLayout: 'App_body',
  defaultContentRegion: 'main',
  defaultLayoutRegions: {}
});


// Define these routes in a file loaded on both client and server
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn', {
  name: 'signin',
  path: '/signin'
});

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signUp', {
  name: 'join',
  path: '/join'
});

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('forgotPwd');

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('resetPwd', {
  name: 'resetPwd',
  path: '/reset-password'
});
```

*note: the "/" route above is my last trial, with direct link to the signin route. No success.*

Also, when I try to insert the {{> atForm}} nothing displays, but I see that an empty div is created with a `class="at-form"`.

Would really appreciate some help on this one, really stucked right now.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, well. Found the answer and might be useful for beginners like me. 
I was still logged in (while I was using accounts-ui), that's the reason why it wouldn't display any of the template to log in or sign up. 
After clearing my browser cache (which logged me out) it solved the issue.

I can now see the login and signup forms as it should be.